# WSL: Used 'sudo reboot' in ubuntu; now everything is down incl. wsl

Tags: windows, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I run WSL on win 10, installed ubuntu 20.04 & used 'sudo reboot' in ubuntu command line;
now everything is down incl. wsl

Means, if I type wsl -l -v in windows power shell, not even that works.

WSL seems to be broken.